# Подсчитать средние значение по условиям. SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

мне надо подсчитать значения по каждому дню:

- общее кол-во записей
- записи, где disposition = "ANSWERED"
- ср. значение duration, где dcontext != "queue-callback"
- ср. значение duration
- ср. значение duration, где dcontext = "queue-callback"

Вот запрос:

```
SELECT
    datenew,
    calls,
    accepted,
    AVG(without_callback),
    AVG(all_calls),
    AVG(only_callback)
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        DATE_FORMAT(c1.calldate, '%Y-%m-%d') as datenew,
        COUNT(1) as calls,
        SUM(IF(c1.disposition = "ANSWERED", 1, 0)) as accepted,
        SUM(IF(c1.dcontext != "queue-callback", c1.duration , 0)) as without_callback,
        SUM(c1.duration) as all_calls,
        SUM(IF(c1.dcontext = "queue-callback", c1.duration , 0)) as only_callback
    FROM
        asteriskcdrdb.cdr c1
    WHERE
        LEFT(c1.lastdata, 3) in ('601', '602') AND 
        DATE_FORMAT(c1.calldate, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN "2020-04-28" AND "2020-05-01"
    GROUP BY
        DATE_FORMAT(c1.calldate, '%Y-%m-%d') 
    ) as tmp
GROUP BY datenew
```

UPD:
Проблема в том, что общее кол-во записей не подсчитывается, а так же не подсчитывает среднее значения по колонкам (выводит только сумму)

Comment: @Akina Внес правки в вопрос

Comment: Так Вы ж сами считаете сумму, а не среднее...

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, так:

```sql
SELECT
       -- дата
       DATE(c1.calldate) as datenew,
       -- всего звонков
       COUNT(1) as calls,
       -- отвеченных
       SUM(c1.disposition = "ANSWERED") as accepted,
       -- среднее для всех, кроме queue-callback
       AVG(CASE WHEN c1.dcontext != "queue-callback" THEN c1.duration END) as without_callback,
       -- среднее для всех
       AVG(c1.duration) as all_calls,
       -- среднее для queue-callback
       AVG(CASE WHEN c1.dcontext = "queue-callback" THEN c1.duration END) as only_callback
FROM asteriskcdrdb.cdr c1
WHERE LEFT(c1.lastdata, 3) in ('601', '602') 
  AND DATE(c1.calldate) BETWEEN "2020-04-28" AND "2020-05-01"
GROUP BY datenew;
```